# Подскажите язык для реализации

Tags: jquery, php, ruby, mysql, javascript

Есть одностраничный сайт, там есть кнопка и два поля для текста, в одно пользователь вводит текст, при нажатии на кнопку, текст должен записаться в файл на сервере (или добавиться к предыдущим, например 14 высказываниям) и затем в другом поле вывести все 15 высказываний из файла, и так последующее высказывание должно заменять первое и т.д. Так вот, на каком из языков программированию это будет лучше всего реализовать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

на любом. выберите, который лучше знаете.

Comment: начни с пхп

Comment: по моему личному мнению начните с php, установите wamp (ссылка: www.wampserver.com/ru/‎) и тренируйтесь на локалхосте очень удобно учитвыая миллион примеров и бесплатных классов в интернете!удачи!

Comment: Не знаете языков программирования серверной части. А какие знаете?

Comment: а я бы с руби/питона начал бы. мне они кажутся проще чем пхп. да и запустить локально абсолютно никаких проблем. ну а, например, популярный питоний веб-фреймвор джанго даже содержит специальный веб-сервер для нужд локальной разработки/отладки